Repeat first row in each five rows five times
I have a panel data frame that contains 960 observations, and I would like to create a new variable which contains the first row for each five rows by country.
df <- data.frame(
  year=rep(c(2001:2010),2),
  country=c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)),
  Old.var= c(12,26,14,9,7,42,13,12,24,13, 19,32,44,63,24,12,16,9,10, 5)
)

 year country Old.var
1  2001       A      12
2  2002       A      26
3  2003       A      14
4  2004       A       9
5  2005       A       7
6  2006       A      42
7  2007       A      13
8  2008       A      12
9  2009       A      24
10 2010       A      13
11 2001       B      19
12 2002       B      32
13 2003       B      44
14 2004       B      63
15 2005       B      24
16 2006       B      12
17 2007       B      16
18 2008       B       9
19 2009       B      10
20 2010       B       5

I need to craate a new column named  new.var which contains the first row of each five rows
df.new <- data.frame(
  year=rep(c(2001:2010),2),
  country=c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)),
  Old.var= c(12,26,14,9,7,42,13,12,24,13, 19,32,44,63,24,12,16,9,10, 5),
  new.var= c(12,12,12,12,12,42,42,42,42,42,19,19,19,19,19,12,12,12,12,12)
  
)
year country Old.var new.var
1  2001       A      12      12
2  2002       A      26      12
3  2003       A      14      12
4  2004       A       9      12
5  2005       A       7      12
6  2006       A      42      42
7  2007       A      13      42
8  2008       A      12      42
9  2009       A      24      42
10 2010       A      13      42
11 2001       B      19      19
12 2002       B      32      19
13 2003       B      44      19
14 2004       B      63      19
15 2005       B      24      19
16 2006       B      12      12
17 2007       B      16      12
18 2008       B       9      12
19 2009       B      10      12
20 2010       B       5      12


Here's a one-liner using base R.
n <- 5
df$new.var <- df$Old.var[(ceiling(seq_len(nrow(df))/n) -1) * n + 1]
df

#   year country Old.var new.var
#1  2001       A      12      12
#2  2002       A      26      12
#3  2003       A      14      12
#4  2004       A       9      12
#5  2005       A       7      12
#6  2006       A      42      42
#7  2007       A      13      42
#8  2008       A      12      42
#9  2009       A      24      42
#10 2010       A      13      42
#11 2001       B      19      19
#12 2002       B      32      19
#13 2003       B      44      19
#14 2004       B      63      19
#15 2005       B      24      19
#16 2006       B      12      12
#17 2007       B      16      12
#18 2008       B       9      12
#19 2009       B      10      12
#20 2010       B       5      12

This works for given data because your data is evenly divisible by 5 for each country.
In case, if it is not then you may use ave to do it via groups.
transform(df, new.var = ave(Old.var, country, FUN = \(x) 
                 x[(ceiling(seq_along(x)/n) - 1) * n + 1]))


One way to approach this is to add a new grouping column to each country, calculated as the integer result of the row number minus one divided by 5 (using %/%, the integer division operator).
Then, within each group and country, you can assign the first value of Old.var to all rows in that group. For example, using dplyr:
library(dplyr)
df |>
    mutate(grp = (row_number() - 1) %/% 5, .by = country) |>
    mutate(new.var = first(Old.var), .by = c(country, grp))

#    year country Old.var grp new.var
# 1  2001       A      12   0      12
# 2  2002       A      26   0      12
# 3  2003       A      14   0      12
# 4  2004       A       9   0      12
# 5  2005       A       7   0      12
# 6  2006       A      42   1      42
# 7  2007       A      13   1      42
# 8  2008       A      12   1      42
# 9  2009       A      24   1      42
# 10 2010       A      13   1      42
# 11 2001       B      19   0      19
# 12 2002       B      32   0      19
# 13 2003       B      44   0      19
# 14 2004       B      63   0      19
# 15 2005       B      24   0      19
# 16 2006       B      12   1      12
# 17 2007       B      16   1      12
# 18 2008       B       9   1      12
# 19 2009       B      10   1      12
# 20 2010       B       5   1      12

You will probably want to drop the grp column but I've left it in so it's clearer how this approach works. In your example, 5 happens to be a factor of the number of rows but this will work even if that is not the case.
base R approach
I think dplyr is quite expressive here but it's not necessary. Here's the same approach in base R:
transform(
    df,
    grp = ave(seq_along(country), country, FUN = \(x) (x - 1) %/% 5),
    new.var = ave(Old.var, country, grp, FUN = \(x) rep(x[1], length(x)))
)
# ^^ same output

